# Loop mysql database names that starts with selected prefix in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

How do i loop only the database names that starts with `solarsystem` inside a dropdown list.

```
+---------------------+
|       dbname        |
+---------------------+
| electronics         |
| vegetables          |
| solarsystem_sun     |
| solarsystem_mercury |
| solarsystem_venus   |
| solarsystem_mars    |
| fruits              |
| foobar              |
+---------------------+
```

Currently it is looping all the database names

```
<div class="select">
    <?php
        $sdbhost = 'localhost';
        $sdbusername = 'root';
        $sdbpassword = '';
        $dbcnx = mysql_connect ($sdbhost, $sdbusername, $sdbpassword);

        $dbresult = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");
            echo "<select name='dbselect'>";
                while ($dbrow = mysql_fetch_array($dbresult)) {
                    echo "<option input value='$dbrow[0]'>" .$dbrow[0]."<br></option>";
                }
            echo "<select>";
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SHOW DATABASES WHERE `Database` LIKE 'solarsystem%'
```

Or

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME
FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'solarsystem%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution that comes in mind:

```
while ($dbrow = mysql_fetch_array($dbresult)) {
    if (strpos($dbrow[0], 'solarsystem') === 0) {
        echo "<option input value='$dbrow[0]'>" .$dbrow[0]."<br></option>";
    }
}
```